# enable ApplicationInsights in Release only

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

In my ASP.NET Core app I want to enable ApplicationInsights for release/production only. To achieve this I need to use three lines of Code conditionally. First two are part of the `_layout.cshtml

```
#if DEBUG
#else
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet JavaScriptSnippet @* does not work this way *@
#endif
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />
#if DEBUG
#else
@Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript) @* does not work this way *@
#endif
</head>

<body style='font-family:"-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, \"Segoe UI\", Roboto, \"Helvetica Neue\", Arial, sans-serif;"'>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync(typeof(Bsoft.Core.Mvc.BannerViewComponent))
    @RenderBody()

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

I tried using #if, but it does not work. The #if will just be shown as html.

Second part is `.UseApplicationInsights()` in program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var host = BuildWebHost(args);
    host.Run();
  }

  public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
  {
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_")
        .Build();
    return new WebHostBuilder()
      .UseConfiguration(config)
      .UseKestrel()
      .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .UseIISIntegration()
      .UseStartup<Startup>()
#if DEBUG
#else
      .UseApplicationInsights() // <= only in release/production 
#endif
      .Build();
  }
}
```

For `.UseApplicationInsights()` I can use #ifndef DEBUG, but how can I apply the changes in `_layout.cshtml` in release only?

Comment: Could you read environment variables or config, and use that to determine whether to call `@Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript)` or not?

Comment: As I wrote in the question, `.UseApplicationInsights` is easy done by using #ifndef DEBUG. But I need to get rid of the other parts in Razor, too (otherwise my end-to-end-tests do not run)

Comment: Add `#if` around the `JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript` part too, leave it blank for debug.

Comment: Note that using conditional compilation (#if) seems not quite right here, because environment type is provided by environment variable (and can be accessed via `IHostingEnvironment`, like `environment.IsProduction()` etc).

Comment: @Evk For `environment.IsProduction()` I would write my own Extension method which can call `.UseApplicationInsights()` depending on the Environment. My problem are the parts in the `.layout.cshtml`.

Comment: @DavidG, I can use #if in the cshtml? I thought they don't work here? What about the `@inject` part?

Comment: @DavidG I tried using #if in razor, it will be parsed and shown as html => does not work.

Comment: I meant to put the `#if` in the code where `JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript` is defined.

Comment: I'd suggest to register wrapper class in container, make that wrapper class look if `JavaScriptSnippet` is registered in container and output empty "script" when not. Then inject that wrapper into view instead of `JavaScriptSnippet`.

Comment: `JavaScriptSnippet` is part of the ASP.NET Core Framework, Namespace `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` - I don't see how to change this...?

Comment: @Sam I don't suggest to change this. I suggest to create your own wrapper around this class. This wrapper will check if real `JavaScriptSnipper` is registered in container (that happens when you call `UseApplicationInsights`) and if yes - will call its `FullScript` to provide a script. Otherwise will just provide empty string. And you inject that wrapper instead of `JavaScriptSnipper` into your view.

Comment: @Evk, ok, that might work - but what about the `@inject` part? It needs to be gone for testing/debugging.

Comment: @Sam you @inject your wrapper as described above. Your wrapper is _always_ injected be it development or production. Just in development environment `YourJavaScriptSnippetWrapper.FullScript` renders empty string instead of insights script.

Comment: another common suggestion is to NOT disable application insights in any specific environment, but instead to swap out the instrumentation key, so that debug telemetry goes to another instance.  That lets you verify telemetry that is being sent in those instances BEFORE they get to production.  This also ensures that you don't have any strange issues in production that can only be explained by some `#if` that might be wrong somewhere including or excluding code you don't expect.

Comment: @JohnGardner Problem is, my end-to-end-Tests using Protractor will not work if any part of application insight is in the code.

Comment: how come?  why do the tests fail with protractor?  if that's the case you should probably post an issue on the application insights github to see what can be done to avoid it.  (i'd think that protractor would just show up as a "synthetic" data source if things were done correctly?)

Comment: Well, I don't see any use in application insights while debugging/testing, so I had no inclination to check this problem.